Equivalence of two definitions of relative limits
This is a question on seemingly equivalent definitions of relative limits, formulated in the language of quasi-categories. I will use notations from Higher Topos Theory.

Let $p:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ be an inner fibration of quasi-categories, let $K$ be a simplicial set, and let $\overline{f}:K^\triangleleft\to\mathcal{C}$ be a diagram. Set $f=\overline{f}\vert K$. Recall that $\overline{f}$ is called a $p$-limit diagram if the map
$$\mathcal{C}_{/\overline{f}}\to\mathcal{C}_{/f}\times_{\mathcal{D}_{/pf}}\mathcal{D}_{/p\overline{f}}$$
is a trivial fibration. As explained in this MO post, the right fibration $\mathcal{C}_{/f}\to \mathcal{C}$ is classified by the functor $C\mapsto \lim_{v\in K}\mathcal{C}(C,f(v))$,
where $\mathcal{C}(-,-)$ denotes the hom-functor for $\mathcal{C}$. Thus, we should be able to reformulate this condition as follows:

(*) For each object $C\in \mathcal{C}$, the square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{C}(C,\overline{f}(-\infty)) @>>> \lim_{v\in K}\mathcal{C}(C,f(v))\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathcal{D}(p(C),p\overline{f}(-\infty)) @>>> \lim_{v\in K}\mathcal{D}(p(C),pf(v))
\end{CD}
is cartesian in $\mathcal{S}$, where $-\infty$ denotes the cone point of $K^\triangleleft$ and the top horizontal maps are the canonical map to the limit induced by the diagram $K^{\triangleleft}\xrightarrow{\overline{f}} \mathcal{C}\xrightarrow{\mathcal{C}(C,-)} \mathcal{S}$ and similarly for the bottom horizontal map.

This should definitely be true, and indeed it is implicit in many literatures, but I do not know how a formal proof should go. The difficult part is to show that the map $\mathcal{C}_{/\overline{f}}\to \mathcal{C}_{/f}$ of right fibrations straightens to the map
$$\mathcal{C}(-,\overline{f}(-\infty))\to \lim_{v\in K}\mathcal{C}(-,f(v))$$
in $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})$, which does not seem to be clear from the proofs outlined in the MO post cited above. Can anyone give me a proof or a reference explaining the equivalence of the two conditions? Thanks in advance.

Let $\mathcal E:=\mathcal C_{/f}$. I think that $\bar f$ defines an object $w$ of $\mathcal E$, and the simplicial sets $\mathcal C_{/\bar f}$ and $\mathcal E_{/w}$ are categorically equivalent (I am not sure whether they are the same as simplicial sets), and you invoke your quoted result to conclude.

@Z.M I understand that $\mathcal{C}/f$ and $\mathcal{E}{/w}$ are equivalent (they are in fact isomorphic as simplicial sets), but I am not sure how I can proceed from there. Can you elaborate a bit more?

If you replace $\mathcal C$ (resp. $\mathcal D$) by $\mathcal C_{/f}$ (resp. $\mathcal D_{/pf}$), then the condition you get is just the special case of relative limits, namely, Cartesian edges. In this case, I think that Lurie proved that these two conditions are the same. Then you unravel these mapping anima (in $\mathcal C_{/f}$ and $\mathcal D_{/pf}$), and seemingly you get your Cartesian square.

@Z.M Sounds nice! But if I replace $\mathcal{C}$ by $\mathcal{C}_{/f}$, then the condition I get is a special case of relative limits, but it is not that of cartesian edges; it is that of relatively terminal object. (In other words, we arrive at the case where $K=\emptyset$, while cartesian edges  correspond to the case where $K=\Delta^0$. )
